# Retrieve objects from object id arrays MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous

I have a city object which has cinemas array. And in this array I keep the cinema ids. What I want to do is to get the cinema objects using the ids but the result I am getting is wrong. This is my Next.js component:

```
import { getCinema, getCityByName } from "@/lib/api";
import styles from "./city.module.css";

const City = async ({ params }) => {
  const { cityName } = params;
  const city = await getCityByName(cityName);
  console.log(city);
  const cinemaNames = [];

  for (let cinemaId of city.cinemas) {
    console.log(cinemaId);
    const cinema = await getCinema(cinemaId);
    cinemaNames.push(cinema);
  }
  console.log(cinemaNames);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <p>{city.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default City;
```

and getCinema function is like this:

```
export const getCinema = async (id) => {
  const cinema = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/cinemas/${id}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 1 },
  });
  return cinema.json();
};
```

And when I run this code I get this output.

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId('65fc33062533d05cf6e4c4c4'),
  name: 'Berlin',
  cinemas: [
    new ObjectId('65fc7ef75d0a65a618d207d4'),
    new ObjectId('65fc82ee5d0a65a618d20807')
  ],
  __v: 2
}
    new ObjectId('65fc7ef75d0a65a618d207d4')
    new ObjectId('65fc82ee5d0a65a618d20807')
[
  {
    _id: '65fc7ef75d0a65a618d207d4',
    name: 'Multi Kino',
    cityId: '65fc33062533d05cf6e4c4c4',
    salons: [ '65fc81ba5d0a65a618d207e7', '65fc81d55d0a65a618d207ef' ],
    __v: 2
  },
  {
    _id: '65fc7ef75d0a65a618d207d4',
    name: 'Multi Kino',
    cityId: '65fc33062533d05cf6e4c4c4',
    salons: [ '65fc81ba5d0a65a618d207e7', '65fc81d55d0a65a618d207ef' ],
    __v: 2
  }
]
```

As you can see I get 2 different ids but my function is called with only the first one apperantly.

what might be causing this?